# How to get rid of html tags when output data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am having a issue with the syntax. How to get rid of html tags in jQuery?

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/populate',
        data: {id: id, '_token':$('input[name=_token]').val()},
        success: function( data ) {
          var results = [
              data.address,
              data.state,
              data.city,
              data.country,
              data.code
          ];

          $("#title").val(data.title);
          $("#address").val(results.map(function(value) {
               return(value + "<br>";
            }).join(""));

        }
    });
```

When displaying results it shows html tag. how to fix it please?

```
9111 Parisian Mountain
Cletamouth, MO 99096-0914<br>Pennsylvania<br>West 
Khalilborough<br>Uzbekistan<br>23457-3306
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are displaying result inside a textarea if so use `\n` instead of `<br>`

`<br>` will work if you are trying to insert line break in html code but as `address` is an input element for new line characters to work you should use `\n`

```js
var results = ["9111 Parisian Mountain Cletamouth, MO 99096-0914","Pennsylvania","West Khalilborough","Uzbekistan","23457-3306"]; 

$("#address").val(results.map(function(value) {
       return(value + "\n");
  }).join(""));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="address" cols="55" rows="5"></textarea>
```

Comment: no problem. if this solution worked , you can accept the answer

Comment: if they let me. get a message saying I will be able to accept in 7 minutes hahha. dont worry. I will sort it out

Answer (score 0):

Use `.html()` instead of `.val()` for HTML

```
  $("#address").html(results.map(function(value) {
       return(value + "<br>");
  }).join(""));
```

http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-htmlString

Comment: i have fixed it with \r\n. thanks for taking your time.